# Substitute plotmath character string into expression

Tags: r, graphics, plot, expression, plotmath

I couldn't find the answer to this in the multitude of similar, but not quite the same questions on the site. Let's say I have a character string in a variable, which is a direct representation of the plotmath expression I want to use, e.g. `"R^2"`. How can I substitute that into an `expression` so it's rendered as plotmath? I'm going crazy trying every combination but I can't get it to work...

```
#  What I want...
mn <- "R^2"
#  Using expression directly to show what I'd like to get
plot( 1 , main = expression(R^2) )
```

[image]

```
#  What I tried to substitute the value of 'mn' into an expression
plot( 1 , main = expression( mn ) )
plot( 1 , main = bquote( .(mn) ) )
plot( 1 , main = bquote( paste( .(mn) ) ) )
plot( 1 , main = do.call( expression , list( mn ) ) )
plot( 1 , main = do.call( expression , list( bquote( .(mn) ) ) ) )
plot( 1 , main = do.call( expression , list( bquote( paste( .(mn) ) ) ) ) ) #getting silly
plot( 1 , main = deparse( substitute( mn , list( mn = mn ) ) ) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, `parse` will do the trick:

```
mn <- "R^2"

plot(1, main = parse(text = mn))
```

[image]

Comment: This does seem to be a good example of a situation where there really is no good alternative to `parse()`, one of the exceptions implied by `fortunes::fortune(106)`.